# How to make "list-divider" item to clickable item

Tags: jquery-mobile

I try to make "list-divider" item (Mail), it can clickable like other item (Inbox, Outbox)

But when i put a tag inside, it's a link like below

[image]

How to make "list-divider" item (Mail) to clickable item like (Inbox, Outbox) item thank

Here is my [code](http://jsfiddle.net/h7Uz2/)

```
<ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-divider-theme="a">
    <li data-role="list-divider"><a href="#">Mail</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Inbox</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Outbox</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Remove anchor, give `li` a class `ui-btn`. http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/h7Uz2/1/

Answer (score 0):

Can try the simplest option

```
<ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-divider-theme="a">
   <li data-role="list-divider" id="lild">Mail</li>
   <li><a href="#">Inbox</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Outbox</a></li>
</ul>

$('#lild').click(function () {
   alert('click on Mail');
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/fSH5S/2/)

Answer (score -1):

Try below code .Hope it will work for you.

```
<ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-divider-theme="a">
    <a href="#"><li data-role="list-divider">Mail</li></a>
    <li><a href="#">Inbox</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Outbox</a></li>
</ul>
```